# chaining methods in base and derived class

Tags: c#

I have 2 classes, one derived from the other:

```
class Animal
{
    public Animal AnimalMethod() 
    {
        // do something 
        return this; 
    }   
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog DogMethod()
    {
         // do something
         return this;
    }
}

var dog = new Dog();
dog.DogMethod().AnimalMethod(); // 1 - this works   
dog.AnimalMethod().DogMethod(); // 2 - this doesn't
```

How can I change my declaration(s) to be able to call the methods in the order "2" above in order to achieve a more fluent api?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Use generic extension methods**

Fluent/chaining methods work best as generic extension methods. A generic extension method knows the type of the instance variable and can return it as the same type that was passed in.

```
class Animal
{
    public string CommonProperty { get; set; }
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    public string DogOnlyProperty { get; set; }
}

static class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public T AnimalMethod<T>(this T o) where T : Animal
    {
        o.CommonProperty = "foo";
        return o;
    }
    static public T DogMethod<T>(this T o) where T : Dog
    {
        o.DogOnlyProperty = "bar";
        return o;
    }

}

class Example
{
    static public void Test()
    {
        var dog = new Dog();
        dog.DogMethod().AnimalMethod(); // 1 - this works   
        dog.AnimalMethod().DogMethod(); // 2 - this works now

        Console.WriteLine("CommonProperty = {0}", dog.CommonProperty);
        Console.WriteLine("DogOnlyProperty = {0}", dog.DogOnlyProperty);

        var animal = new Animal();
        animal.AnimalMethod();
        //animal.DogMethod();                //Does not compile
        //animal.AnimalMethod().DogMethod(); //Does not compile
    }
}
```

Output:

> CommonProperty = foo
>
> DogOnlyProperty = bar

**A workaround if you need private/protected access**

One disadvantage of extension methods is that they cannot access private or protected members. Your instance method could. This hasn't been a problem for me (and it seems it's not an issue for the entire LINQ library either, which are written as extension methods). But there is a workaround if you need access.

You will need to implement the "chaining" method twice-- once as an interface method on the instance and a simple wrapper (one line of code) as an extension method that simply calls the first method. We use an interface method on the instance so that the compiler won't try to pick the instance method over the extension method.

```
interface IPrivateAnimal
{
    Animal AnimalMethod();
}

interface IPrivateDog
{
    Dog DogMethod();
}

class Animal : IPrivateAnimal
{
    protected virtual string CommonProperty { get; set; }  //notice this is nonpublic now

    Animal IPrivateAnimal.AnimalMethod()  //Won't show up in intellisense, as intended
    {
        this.CommonProperty = "plugh";
        return this;
    }
}

class Dog : Animal, IPrivateDog
{
    private string DogOnlyProperty { get; set; }  //notice this is nonpublic now

    Dog IPrivateDog.DogMethod()  //Won't show up in intellisense
    {
        this.DogOnlyProperty = "xyzzy";
        return this;
    }
}

static class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public T AnimalMethod<T>(this T o) where T : class, IPrivateAnimal
    {
        return o.AnimalMethod() as T;  //Just pass control to our hidden instance method
    }
    static public T DogMethod<T>(this T o) where T : class, IPrivateDog
    {
        return o.DogMethod() as T;  //Just pass control to the instance method
    }
}

class Example
{
    static public void Test()
    {
        var dog = new Dog();
        dog.DogMethod().AnimalMethod(); 
        dog.AnimalMethod().DogMethod(); 


        Console.WriteLine("CommonProperty = {0}", typeof(Dog).GetProperty("CommonProperty", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(dog));
        Console.WriteLine("DogOnlyProperty = {0}", typeof(Dog).GetProperty("DogOnlyProperty", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(dog));
    }
}
```

Output:

> CommonProperty = plugh
>
> DogOnlyProperty = xyzzy

Comment: In fairness; LINQ has the advantage of just being a set of `foreach` loops, no private access needed

Answer (score 6):

There is one trick you could use to do this; though I'm not sure I would recommend it. Make `Animal` generic and all your fluent methods return the type parameter:

```
class Animal<T> where T : Animal<T>
{
    public T AnimalMethod() { return (T)this; }
}
```

Now your Dog inherits from the Dog form of animal

```
class Dog : Animal<Dog>
{
    public Dog DogMethod() { return this; }
}
```

Now since the initial method will return a `Dog`, you can call `DogMethod` on it. This will be **very** hard to read; but it would accomplish your goal.

<sub>I did test this in C# interactive and it appears to work.</sub>

Apparently this is called the "Curiously Recurring" Pattern among other things. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: ah, the "curiously recurring" pattern; always good for a Friday evening!

Comment: lol @MarcGravell - or when you're doing low latency C++ and have to unit test :P

Comment: @MarcGravell lol, apparently this even has a name. I thought I was just making up some horrible hack :)

Comment: this is very close to what I was aiming for. why would you advice against it? just readability?

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev Yeah; because somebody is going to have a serious WTF when they read that type constraint (and the fact that it is at all generic anyways). I don't think it *hurts* anything; it just looks really weird and the intended effect is not obvious.

Comment: @Bradley it has multiple names - the functional crowd would call it "F-bound polymorphism". Seriously, I'm not making this up.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah; I saw that in the wiki post. At least "Curiously recurring" makes some sort of sense :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET this is even more creative than the usual CRTP since CRTP is normally concerned more with static polymorphism of implementation (method body) rather than the return type :)  Very nice thinking there!

Comment: @hoodaticus This is just going to keep getting funnier... I swear I had no idea this was actually a thing 10 minutes ago.

Comment: Probably not the best answer for the question, but I'm upvoting because the answer is useful anyway, since I learned something new!

Comment: @JohnWu I won't argue with you there; extension methods are the "classic" way of doing FluentAPI. I would probably consider this over the "wrapper" you have for private member access though.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yeah I've never actually used that pattern in my example, I just thought it was a neat challenge.

Answer (score 2):

The only *simple* way to do that would be (in `Dog`):

```
public new Dog AnimalMethod() 
{
    base.AnimalMethod();
    return this; 
}
```

This is "method hiding".

Comment: That's what I have now and trying to avoid. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you should avoid it in this case.  If it gives you all the syntax and behavior you want then go for it.